# Error in a trigger getting updates from a field

Tags: sql, triggers

i have a problem with a trigger. I have a trigger to save a field change in other table:

```
    CREATE trigger [dbo].[ReferenceChanges] on [dbo].[PPRR_PPRR_00000100] for update
as
If (Update(PrdRef)) begin

      declare @Recid int
      declare @LastUser nvarchar(40)
      declare @OldPrdRef nvarchar(40)
      declare @NewPrdRef nvarchar(40)
      declare @ExecStr varchar(max), @Qry nvarchar(max)

      select  @Recid = RecId, @LastUser = LastUser, @NewPrdRef = PrdRef from inserted

      select  @OldPrdRef = PrdRef from deleted

        CREATE TABLE #inputbuffer 
        (
                EventType nvarchar(30), 
                Parameters int, 
                EventInfo nvarchar(max)
        )

        SET @ExecStr = 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + STR(@@SPID) + ')'

        INSERT INTO #inputbuffer 
        EXEC (@ExecStr)

        SET @Qry = (SELECT EventInfo FROM #inputbuffer)

        insert into AAA_ReferenceChanges (RecId, App, OldPrdRef, NewPrdRef, [User], Date) values (@Recid, app_name(), @OldPrdRef, @NewPrdRef, @LastUser, GetDate())

        drop table #inputbuffer

end
```

After creating this trigger, when i change "PrdRef" field i get an error:

```
No row was updated.

The data in row 1 was not committed.
Error Source: M8icrosoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.
Error Message: The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple row(3 row).
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. As such, this trigger is broken.